# want to add configurable swatches on home page category

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, development

I have created a costume list page namely **home_list.phtml** and call it on cms home page all work are fine but color configurable swatches are not showing on **home_list.phtml** home page. what should I do.

thank you

Comment: are you using default `rwd` theme OR installed any other ?

Comment: Do you find solution